# Node js counter value wont increment

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So the idea is that it get the instance of teamInfo, which each each team it then get the game info and updates the game info when there is a match and I want the counter to increment on each match found and then finally output the total count of matches (or updates) made to the game info.

My code is the following:

```
let counter = 0;
teams.once("value", teamSnap => {
    teamSnap.forEach(tSnap => {
        games.once("value", gameSnap => {
            gameSnap.forEach(gSnap => {
                if(teamInfo.Name == gameInfo.AwayTeam) {
                    let currGame = games.child(`${gSnap.key}`);

                    currGame.update({
                    "AwayTeam": teamInfo.Name,
                    "AwayId": tSnap.key}),
                    function(error){
                        if (error) {
                             console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
                        } else {             
                             counter++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Final Count: " + counter)
});
```

When I call the `console.log("Final Count: " + counter)` it displays zero (0), I am not sure why it doesn't increment?!

Comment: where do you put your `console.log( counter );` statement?

Comment: it is at the end, and the init of the counter is prior and set to zero (0) which is why is displays zero.

Comment: Your code is asynchronous. Basically the console.log statement is being fired before your update callnack updates

Comment: @Chris im confused how to setup the promise to ensure the counter only displays after all the operations are completed?!

Comment: You need to increment your counter in the callback function of your update query.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj the counter increments correctly, but its like Chris stated the console print statement executes prior to the counter being incremented so it prints zero (0). I need to put a completion handler on the main function but I'm confused on how to do so!?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your counter in the promise returned by the [`.update` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#update) and then print your console log

```
if(teamInfo.Name == gameInfo.AwayTeam) {
   let currGame = games.child(`${gSnap.key}`);

   currGame.update({
      "AwayTeam": teamInfo.Name,
      "AwayId": tSnap.key})
   .then(() => {
      counter++
      console.log(counter)
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
   })
}
```

If you want to use your existing code:

```
if(teamInfo.Name == gameInfo.AwayTeam) {
   let currGame = games.child(`${gSnap.key}`);

   currGame.update({
      "AwayTeam": teamInfo.Name,
      "AwayId": tSnap.key}),
       function(error){
          if (error) {
               console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
          } else {             
               counter++;
               console.log(counter) //You should log your counter here...
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: logon the counter after i increment always worked, but what I want by outputting the counter after the full execution is to know how many times it was successful, or how many updates were made overall.

Comment: the code you provided gives the same behavior I already have.

Comment: The logging after the counter has been incremented inside the callback / promise should definately work. Weird that it doesn't. Are you using the exact code as above?

Comment: yes, the code provided will display the counter over every iteration of the teaminfo and gameinfo compare, but I want the overall "final count" after all the iterations which still produces zero (0)

Comment: the console.log("Final Count: " + counter) gets called instantly when I wish it to only be called after all the iterations are completed!?

Comment: any further comment or ideas?

Comment: i am also confront with the same situation lie not able to get the counter of how many times successful query has executed in a loop.